# Send signal with boolean argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside, signals-slots

File 1:

```
class A(QObject):
    status = Signal()
.
.
def func1(self, boolean_var):
    self.emit.status()
```

File 2:

```
class B(QMainWindow):
.
.
self.model.status.connect(self.update)
@Slot()
def update(self):
    # here i have to process data based on the boolean argument passed through signal
```

I have used signal() without arguments here, but how can i add an argument to it here ?

Comment: Is it pyside or pyqt? Please read the [tag:qt] wiki because QT is a different project than the one you are referring to.

Comment: @LaszloPapp its PySide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy if you [read the documentation](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtCore/Signal.html)

```
from PySide import QtCore


class A(QtCore.QObject):
    status = QtCore.Signal(bool)

    def func1(self, *args):
        self.status.emit(*args)

# later...


@QtCore.Slot(bool)
def update(self, bool_args):
    pass  # insert what you need to do here.
```